# Run Powershell as administrator with Terminal Sublime Text 3

Tags: powershell, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How can I run PowerShell as administrator with [Terminal](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal) in Sublime Text 3?

Here is the default configuration:

```javascript
{
    // The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
    // See https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal#examples for examples
    "terminal": "",

    // A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
    // overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
    // dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
    // commands
    "parameters": [],

    // An environment variables changeset. Default environment variables used for the
    // terminal are inherited from sublime. Use this mapping to overwrite/unset. Use
    // null value to indicate that the environment variable should be unset.
    "env": {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** Run Sublime Text as administrator. The process started by the Terminal plugin will run under the administrator user as well. Be careful—third-party plugins will also have admin privileges.

**Option 2:** Configure the Terminal plugin to start a new PowerShell instance that runs as an administrator:

```
"terminal": "powershell.exe",
"parameters": [
    "-WindowStyle", "Hidden", 
    "-Command", "Start-Process", "-Verb", "RunAs", "powershell.exe",
    "-ArgumentList", "'-NoExit', '-Command', Set-Location, \"'$PWD'\""
],
```

This configuration launches a command that restarts PowerShell under an admin user. We manually reset the working directory because the new instance starts in a different process space. When UAC is enabled, we'll need to confirm execution within the UAC prompt that appears to escalate privileges. If desired, we can [disable the prompt](https://superuser.com/q/99286/774787) for a specific program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that talks to your use case using a plug in.

"Wouldn’t it be great if Sublime allowed you to run bash or PowerShell from its popup terminal?"

[sublimetexttips.com/how-to-open-terminal-or-powershell-from-your-sublime-project](http://sublimetexttips.com/how-to-open-terminal-or-powershell-from-your-sublime-project)

Comment: I already use "Terminal" plugin. This article is very old. I know how to run "Terminal" plugin, I dont know how to run it as admin via "Terminal" plugin.

Comment: I have not really needed to use Sublime in years. The link given was from my archives and what I used then. Since PoShv3 ISE and higher and VSCode for PoSH, I don't need Sublime. However, even if you can't do this natively in Sublime, you can always elevate PoSH directly to admin level. Which is documented on TechNet, MSDN and many other locations. Just use... Start-Process PowerShell -Verb runAs. and respond to the UAC prompt. It's an extra step, sure, a hack for a tool not designed for PoSH use case explicitly.